# 3D model using sequence of images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, 2d-3d-conversion

I want to make a project in which we can make 3D model of a object using sequences of images. So I want to know:

1. How can I make 3D model using sequences of 2D images?
2. Is there any tutorial for it either on any website or in PDF format?

I searched on opencv's website but I couldn't find topic related to 3D model.

Comment: Google "structure from motion".

Comment: also "3D stereoscopy reconstruction".... Do you have info about the camera positions and orientations in space while images was taken?  Are the images inconsistent snaps or a video like consistent stream of images ?

Answer (score 2):

Here openCV SfM module documentation: [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d7c/tutorial_table_of_content_sfm.html)